# Rails db query uniq column value and max value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to query db unique values and maximum value of another column.

For example:

```
:name => "some_name_1", :version => 10, :other_columns...
:name => "some_name_1", :version => 11, :other_columns...
:name => "some_name_2", :version => 15, :other_columns...
:name => "some_name_3", :version => 18, :other_columns...
```

What I would need is if the name show up multiple times the query should return only the one with the last version ( higher version number )

So it should look like this :

```
:name => "some_name_1", :version => 11, :other_columns...
:name => "some_name_2", :version => 15, :other_columns...
:name => "some_name_3", :version => 18, :other_columns...
```

note that `:name => "some_name_1", :version => 10, :other_columns...`
those not show in the query because a record with the same name already exist with a hither version number.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
Table.select("tables.name, MAX(tables.version)").group("tables.name")
```

If you need to get other_columns too you have to apply to them some aggregare function (like it is done for **version** column with MAX aggregate function. Or you can specify other columns in the **group** clause to avoid using aggregate functions (only if value of each other column is the same for each the same value of **name** column)

```
Table.select("tables.name, MAX(tables.version), tables.other_column1, tables.other_column2").group("tables.name, tables.other_column1, tables.other_column2")
```